# Is it possible to arrange Python classes/functions into package namespaces, avoiding the module namespace?

Tags: python

Lets' say I have the following structure of my files:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── ClassB0.py
│   │   ├── ClassB1.py
│   │   ├── functionB.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── ClassA0.py
│   ├── ClassA1.py
│   ├── functionA.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

The idea is that each file holds one class or one function - for example `ClassB0.py` has `class ClassB0: ...` and `functionA.py` has `def functionA(): ...`. However I would like to be able to access these classes/functions with the prefixes, but only the prefixes related to folders. So I would like to be able to do something like that in any of the files, anywhere in this tree (assuming that Python is always started in the top-level folder):

```
a.b.functionB()
a.b.ClassB1()
a.ClassA1()
a.functionA()
```

What I would like to avoid is using prefixes of folders and files:

```
a.b.functionB.functionB()
a.b.ClassB1.ClassB1()
a.ClassA1.ClassA1()
a.functionA.functionA()
```

I've tried doing that by putting following code in `__init__.py` files:

```
from .ClassB0 import ClassB0
from .ClassB1 import ClassB1
from .functionB import functionB
```

This works fine for one "level" (so without `b/`) or for very simple classes. But the twist is that `ClassB1` needs `ClassB0` and this breaks the whole thing by causing cyclic dependency (at least I think that's the root cause of my problem). If I try to run my script, I get errors like this:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File "/home/freddie/test/testpy/a/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functionA import functionA
  File "/home/freddie/test/testpy/a/functionA.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a.b
  File "/home/freddie/test/testpy/a/b/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .ClassB1 import ClassB1
  File "/home/freddie/test/testpy/a/b/ClassB1.py", line 3, in <module>
    class ClassB1(a.b.ClassB0):
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'b'
```

For the reference, here's the complete code of these files.

`test.py`

```
import a

a.functionA()
```

`a/ClassA0.py`

```
class ClassA0:
    def __init__(self):
        print('ClassA0')
```

`a/ClassA1.py`

```
import a

class ClassA1(a.ClassA0):
    def __init__(self):
        a.ClassA0.__init__(self)
        print('ClassA1')
```

`a/functionA.py`

```
import a.b
import a

def functionA():
    a.ClassA1()
    a.b.functionB()
```

`a/__init__.py`

```
from .ClassA0 import ClassA0
from .ClassA1 import ClassA1
from .functionA import functionA
```

`a/b/ClassB0.py`

```
class ClassB0:
    def __init__(self):
        print('ClassB0')
```

`a/b/ClassB1.py`

```
import a.b

class ClassB1(a.b.ClassB0):
    def __init__(self):
        a.b.ClassB0.__init__(self)
        print('ClassB1')
```

`a/b/functionB.py`

```
import a.b

def functionB():
    a.b.ClassB1()
```

`a/b/__init__.py`

```
from .ClassB0 import ClassB0
from .ClassB1 import ClassB1
from .functionB import functionB
```

Is there any way I could solve this issue (without resorting to low-level hacks in Python import system)? Maybe I'm just too used to the way C++ namespaces work and this just cannot be done in Python?

As I wrote earlier, I'm trying to have a structure that would allow me to use fully qualified names, but without the name of the module, so only package names. I would also like to avoid having to rename all my classes/functions to sth like `A_B_ClassB1`, as this doesn't look good (; I'm not a Python expert, so maybe the structure of files that I used or the method that I tried (with importing in `__init__.py` files) is not good - I'm open to any suggestion that would allow me to use names like `a.b.ClassB1`, but with some form of keeping the similar organization at the folder/file level.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good idea but you are ignoring the features that Python is built around.

A Python package is a collection of modules that are somehow related.

A Python module is a single file which houses a set of classes and/or functions that work together.

You should not have a class or function per file. That's not good design.

Comment: The problem with the approach that you described is that when there are many classes which are pretty long, the file (module) which houses them becomes pretty hard to grasp... That is another thing I would like to avoid (; Yes, IDE can help with that, but sometimes you read the file without the IDE and then it's much simpler to open single file with class than to open a 10000 lines long single file with 20 classes...

Comment: That may well be the result but it is better than opening many files to grasp what is going on. Also quite often you will have many classes related by inheritance. It's far better to have them in one module than doing imports to satisfy that.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to mess with the import system to make `a.b.ClassB1` refer to a class in the `a/b/ClassB1` file is messy business. It's not quite the direct cause of your error, but it introduces a number of additional complications and makes the problem generally harder to solve.

I would recommend at least naming the class and the file different things, like a `_ClassB1.py` file and a `ClassB1` class, so you can refer to the class and the module separately without ambiguity. This will be important.

---

At the point where `a/b/ClassB1.py` tries to refer to `a.b.ClassB0`, the module object for the `a.b` module has not actually been assigned to the `b` attribute of the `a` module object. That only happens once the `__init__.py` for `a.b` finishes execution, and that `__init__.py` is still going. You can't refer to `a.b` until the `a.b` attribute assignment takes place.

Aside from the attribute assignment problem, `ClassB1.py` is also assuming that `a.b.ClassB0` is the class instead of the module, which means it's assuming that `from .ClassB0 import ClassB0` appears before `from .ClassB1 import ClassB1` in `__init__.py`. This introduces import ordering requirements that would cause other nasty headaches if the `a.b` problem didn't strike first.

To fix this, you can use relative imports to access sibling modules and their contents without trying to access the `a.b` attribute. This becomes much more confusing with your structure, unfortunately, because the meaning of something like `from . import ClassB0` inside `ClassB1.py` depends on whether `__init__.py` has performed the same import yet. If you change the file names to not conflict with the class names, things become less confusing:

```
# _ClassB1.py
from ._ClassB0 import ClassB0

class ClassB1(ClassB0):
    ...
```